# while starting the server in the eclipse IDE I am facing the following error

Tags: tomcat

the error is "The server cannot be started because one or more of the ports are invalid. Open the server editor and correct the invalid ports."

I tried to restart my eclipse IDE but nothing happened, now how can I proceed further